# MSSQL, JSON, UTF8 get them to work together

Tags: php, sql-server, json, utf-8

I was having problems on my webpages where I ran json_encode on strings and lost them because they had special characters. I've now worked on a test script that I run from my Linux terminal to find out what happens. I've now been able to get my outputs and everything in UTF-8 but still when I want to JSON something I have to utf8_encode ($string) of something that is already utf-8 for some reaoson.. I would really like to clean this solution so that I don't have to run utf8_encode anymore.

Test function:

```
function dbConnect() {
    $link = mssql_connect('*******', '*******', '*******');
    mssql_select_db('*******', $link);
    @mssql_query('SET ANSI_NULLS ON; SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;', $link);
    if (!$link) {
        echo "<p>Errore connessione db</p>";
        exit();
    }
    return $link;
}

function matchCode($table) {

$result = Array();
    $result['data'] = false;
    $result['info'] = "";
    $link = dbConnect();
    $query = mssql_query("exec MatchCodeList 0, '$table'", $link);
    if(!$query) {
        $result['info'] = mssql_get_last_message();
        echo "Error: " . $result['info'] . "<br>";
    } else {
        $result['data'] = Array();
        while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($query)) {
            $current_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($row[1], 'auto');
            echo $row[0] . ": " . $row[1] . " (" . $current_encoding . ")\n";
            //$row[1] = utf8_encode($row[1]);
            echo "   ==> " . $row[1] . "\n\n";
            array_push($result['data'], $row);
        }
    }
    mssql_close($link);
    $j = json_encode($result);
    var_dump($j);
    return $result;
}


matchCode("ACT_TSTA");
exit();
```

This function outputs:

```
10: Attività pianificata (UTF-8)
   ==> Attività pianificata

20: Attività sospesa (UTF-8)
   ==> Attività sospesa

30: Attività non effettuata (UTF-8)
   ==> Attività non effettuata

50: Attività in corso (UTF-8)
   ==> Attività in corso

99: Attività conclusa (UTF-8)
   ==> Attività conclusa

00: Attività annullata (UTF-8)
   ==> Attività annullata

string(206) "{"data":[["10",null,null,1,null,0,null],["20",null,null,2,null,0,null],["30",null,null,3,null,0,null],["50",null,null,4,null,0,null],["99",null,null,5,null,0,null],["00",null,null,6,null,0,null]],"info":""}"
```

Instead if I uncomment the utf8_encode this is what I get:

```
10: Attività pianificata (UTF-8)
   ==> AttivitÃ  pianificata

20: Attività sospesa (UTF-8)
   ==> AttivitÃ  sospesa

30: Attività non effettuata (UTF-8)
   ==> AttivitÃ  non effettuata

50: Attività in corso (UTF-8)
   ==> AttivitÃ  in corso

99: Attività conclusa (UTF-8)
   ==> AttivitÃ  conclusa

00: Attività annullata (UTF-8)
   ==> AttivitÃ  annullata

string(335) "{"data":[["10","Attivit\u00e0 pianificata",null,1,null,0,null],["20","Attivit\u00e0 sospesa",null,2,null,0,null],["30","Attivit\u00e0 non effettuata",null,3,null,0,null],["50","Attivit\u00e0 in corso",null,4,null,0,null],["99","Attivit\u00e0 conclusa",null,5,null,0,null],["00","Attivit\u00e0 annullata",null,6,null,0,null]],"info":""}"
```

As I said I would like to remove utf8_encode but get a correct json_encode, seen as I don't understand why I should utf8_encode something that is already utf8 as mb_detect_encoding shows.